# What do two consecutive parameter definitions mean for a function in C?

Tags: c, function, embedded

I am going through the source code at work and I keep seeing this function definition style:

```
FUNC(Std_ReturnType, SMTN_CODE)SendSignalArray(uint8* NUMPTR, int size) {
}
```

What does it mean/do?
Thanks

Comment: `FUNC` is either a macro or some compiler extension. We can' know for sure what it means.

Comment: Compiler, system and library are kinda relevant here...

Comment: I've found [K-OS compiler.h](https://github.com/christoph2/k-dk/blob/master/inc/kdk/common/Compiler.h#L127) which led me to [autosar section 9.2](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/2-0/AUTOSAR_SWS_CompilerAbstraction.pdf). I guess the `SMTN_CODE` is a compiler extension like `__attribute__` in GCC. So for compilers that do not support `SMTN_CODE` they do `#define FUNC(a, b) a`. I guess that someone who worked with autosar needs to answer it, I only guess. The description in autosar 9.2.1 actually explains it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Looks like completely useless macro to me

Comment: @EugeneSh.  It is only "useless" in the sense that it does nothing on some platforms.  The K-OS  implementation is `#define  FUNC(rettype, memclass)                   memclass rettype` so it is used to declare a function that has a memory class specifier.  `#define FUNC(a, b) a` is then "useful" in the sense that it allows identical source code to be used on platforms that do not need memory class specifiers.

Comment: @KamilCuk : I think that is an answer - consider posting an answer rather then a comment.

Comment: Certainly FUNC and probably SMTN_CODE are macros - search the source code (including library headers) for their definitions and expand them to see what is really happening.

Answer (score 2):

This is from AUTOSAR CompilerAbstraction 
`FUNC(rettype, memclass)` is defined usually in Compiler.h and Compiler_Cfg.h. Include hierarchy is:

```
file.c
    Std_Types.h
        Compiler.h
            Compiler_Cfg.h
```

Compiler_Cfg.h is usually configured in the AUTOSAR stack configuration tool, and then generated. Some compilers / architectures still might require the usage of `@far` and `@near` for data access, or some compilers supporting `#pragma section ...`, while other compilers only `__attribute__(( ... ))`.

There is another code part you did not mention here, which comes from AUTOSAR MemoryMapping:

```
#define XXX_START_SEC_...
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

...

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_...
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"
```

Here is an example for the usage, consider a module XXX:

1. XXX.c - impl
2. XXX.h - external interface provided by XXX
3. XXX_Cfg.h - PRECOMPILE configuration header
4. XXX_LCfg.h - LINKTIME configuration header
5. XXX_LCfg.c - LINKTIME configuration impl (e.g. callouts)
6. XXX_PBCfg.h - POSTBUILD configuration header
7. XXX_PBCfg.c - POSTBUILD configuration impl
8. XXX_MemMap.h - Memory Mapping for module XXX

The files 1 and 2 are static code, maybe with optional code wrapped by compiler/feature switches. The rest is usually generated by a configuration tool.

XXX.h:

```
#include "Std_Types.h"
#include "XXX_Cfg.h"
#if (XXX_LCFG_SUPPORT == STD_ON)
#include "XXX_LCfg.h"
#endif
#if (XXX_POSTBUILD_SUPPORT == STD_ON)
#include "XXX_PBCfg.h"
#endif

#define XXX_FOO_DISABLED 0u
#define XXX_FOO_ENABLED  1u

// --- Functions
#define XXX_START_SEC_CODE
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

FUNC(void, XXX_CODE) XXX_Init(P2CONST(XXX_ConfigType, AUTOMATIC, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) ConfigPtr);
FUNC(Std_ReturnType, XXX_CODE)  XXX_IsDetectionEnabled(void);

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"
```

XXX_PBCfg.h:

```
typedef struct {
    VAR(uint8, TYPEDEF) NumChn;
    VAR(uint8, TYPEDEF) FooInitStatus;
    P2CONST(uint8, TYPEDEF, TYPEDEF)  ChannelCfgPtr;
} XXX_ConfigType;

#define XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

EXTERN CONST(XXX_ConfigType, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) XXX_Config;

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"
```

XXX_PBCfg.c:

```
#include "XXX.h"
#define XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

STATIC CONST(uint8, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) XXX_InitVals[] = {
    10,
    20,
    30,
};

EXTERN CONST(XXX_ConfigType, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) XXX_FooInit = {
    sizeof(XXX_InitVals)/sizeof(XXX_InitVals[0]),
    XXX_FOO_ENABLED,
    XXX_InitVals,
};

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"
```

XXX.c

```
// --- Variables
#define XXX_START_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

VAR(uint8, XXX_DATA) XXX_DetectEnable = 0;
P2CONST(XXX_Config, XXX_DATA, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) XXX_ConfigPtr = NULL_PTR;

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_VAR_ASILB_8
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

// --- Functions
#define XXX_START_SEC_CODE
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"

FUNC(void, XXX_CODE) XXX_Init(P2CONST(XXX_ConfigType, AUTOMATIC, XXX_CONFIG_DATA) ConfigPtr)
{
    if (ConfigPtr != NULL)
    {
        XXX_ConfigPtr = ConfigPtr;
        XXX_DetectEnable = ConfigPtr->FooInitValue;
    }
}
FUNC(Std_ReturnType, XXX_CODE)  XXX_IsDetectionEnabled(void)
{
    return XXX_DetectEnable;
}

#define XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE
#include "XXX_MemMap.h"
```

`XXX_MemMap.h` is now generated depending on the configuration, e.g for a DIAB or TASKING compiler like this:

```
#if defined(XXX_START_SEC_CODE)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CODE
#pragma section CODE ".text_ASILB"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE
#pragma section CODE /* default section e.g. .text */

#elif defined(XXX_START_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8
#pragma section DATA ".bss_asilb" ".data_asilb"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8
#pragma section DATA /* default section e.g. .data */

#elif defined(XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#pragma section CONST ".rodata_pbconfig"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#pragma section CONST

#else
    #error "MemClass not defined"
#endif
```

the Compiler_Cfg.h should configure the FUNC(), VAR(), CONST() as:

```
#define FUNC(rettype, memclass)  rettype
#define VAR(t, memclass)  t
#define CONST(t, memclass)  const t
```

or with a compiler not understanding `#pragma section` like gcc using the `__attribute__((section *section-name*))`:

```
#if defined(XXX_START_SEC_CODE)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CODE
#define XXX_CODE ".text_ASILB"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CODE
/* attribute is only on a single entity */

#elif defined(XXX_START_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8
#define XXX_DATA ".data_asilb"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_VAR_INIT_ASILB_8
/* attribute is only on a single entity */

#elif defined(XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA)
#undef XXX_START_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
#define XXX_CONFIG_DATA ".rodata_pbconfig"

#elif defined(XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA)
#undef XXX_STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA
/* attribute is only on a single entity */

#else
    #error "MemClass not defined"
#endif
```

Therefore, the Compiler_Cfg.h should define the FUNC() macros as:

```
#define FUNC(rettype, memclass)   __attribute__((section memclass)) rettype
#define VAR(t, memclass)          __attribute__((section memclass)) t
#define CONST(t, memclass)        __attribute__((section memclass)) const t
```

This might look strange in the code, but at least it does not clutter the code with:

```
#if __DIAB__
  #pragma section CODE ".text_asilb"
#elif __MSVC__
   /* No Mapping */
#elif __GCC__
   __attribute__((section ".text_asilb"))
#endif
  void XXX_Init(XXX_ConfigType *ConfigPtr)
  {
      ... 
  }
```

And the part for `XXX_START/STOP_SEC_CONFIG_DATA`allows also to collect and place *POSTBUILD_LOADABLE* configuration data in a specific memory section (e.g. FLASH Block), which can later separately be replaced by a donwload tool with different data without reflashing the whole application.
Consider here a use case like a gateway which just needs a new network routing table.